# Does Apportable support toll-free bridging?

Tags: apportable

Does Apportable (beta1) support Toll-free bridging between CF types and NS types just like Apple's implementation? If it's partially supported, how can I get the list of classes which support it?

If it's not yet, is it planned or won't be available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we do!  We support bridging on most of the classes (CFString->NSString, CFDictionary->NSDictionary, CFArray->NSArray, CFSet->NSSet, CFDate->NSDate, CFNumber->NSNumber, CFStream*->NS*Stream, etc).  Some of the lesser known and used ones (mostly those deal with timezones, locales, and ICU), we may not have fully bridged just yet (eg CFTimeZoneRef, CFCalendar).